# Значение выражения "Козёл отпущения"

Tags: фразеология

Каково значение фразеологизма "козёл отпущения?"

Answer (score 1):

Значение: человек, который вынужден отвечать за вину других, на которого сваливают вину. От существовавшего у древних евреев обряда: в день отпущения грехов первосвященник возлагал обе руки на голову живого козла, перенося тем самым на него все грехи еврейского народа, после этого козел изгонялся в пустыню.

Comment: Спасибо, так я и думала.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю. Козёл в пустыню *отпускался*, отсюда не только "козёл *отпущения*", но значение "*отпустить* грехи".